# Conda activate has no effect

Tags: python, windows, powershell

tried to install anaconda on my friend's PC and run into this problem[I fixed it, but couldn't find an answer so i want to post it here]
the PC just wont load anaconda environment, 
when you type

```
>>conda activate base
>>conda info

 active environment : None
```

python works but with this warning

```
>> python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333046/45375) does with custom code - **adding Conda activation code to PowerShell's profile (initialization file), `$PROFILE`** -  already comes prepackaged with `conda`'s `init` command:

```
conda init powershell
```

See [the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#conda-init) or run `conda init --help`.

Note, however, that there seems to be [an issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8234) with activating yet *another* base environment when Conda is initialized globally this way.

A comment in the linked issue from March 2019 states:

> In the meantime, you should be able to `conda install powershell_shortcut` to use the alternative way that does not require `conda init`. It has not seen much testing, so any feedback you have is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So how to fix:

First we need to enable scripts in powershell so we run this.

```
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

This answer is anywhere in the internet but in my case it didn't fix the issue.
in my case the powershell didn't have a profile and those didnt load the necessary stuff.

so we need to create a profile, by typing into powershell:

```
PS> New-Item –Path $Profile –Type File –Force
```

> that would create a new profile file.
>
> like profile.ps1
>
> in \Documents\WindowsPowerShell\

then we will add the following code into the file

```
#region conda initialize
    # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    (& "$PathToAnaconda\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
    #endregion
```

and this is it, next time you open a PowerShell session you would get this message,

```
Loading personal and system profiles took 1453ms.
```

and environments should work just fine.

Comment: Isn't that what `conda init powershell` does _automatically_?

Comment: hmm maybe but i didnt saw anywhere that asnwer :D
so tnx you for letting me know now!

Comment: hmm maybe but i didn't find anything about conda init powershell,
strange considering i found this way XD

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `conda activate base` instead of just `activate base`?

On my system `get-command activate` shows that `activate` picks up `activate.bat` which is not powershell-aware. `conda` binds to a powershell function created by the conda ps module.

It seems that the powershell hook is adding too much to path, but it is not clear to me what the intended setup is.

**Edit**:

Just added the following to my `profile.ps1` to get `activate`/`deactivate` working. Only drawback is that you don't get tab-completion this way.

```
function anaconda_activate([string]$environment) {invoke-conda activate $environment}
New-Alias -Force activate anaconda_activate

function anaconda_deactivate {invoke-conda deactivate}
New-Alias -Force deactivate anaconda_deactivate
```